# How can I mutate/group an array with duplicate values to single unique rows with an array for non-unique values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects possibly containing duplicate values. A cars array containing same brand and model but with different car types. I want each unique brand/model combination on a single row with an array per row containing the car types.

```
-- Received array structure
const carsInitialArray = [
  { brand: "Opel", model: "Astra", carType: "Sedan" },
  { brand: "Opel", model: "Astra", carType: "Hatchback" },
  { brand: "Opel", model: "Astra", carType: "Stationwagon" },
  { brand: "Opel", model: "Corsa", carType: "Hatchback" },
  { brand: "Opel", model: "Zafira", carType: "SUV" },
];

-- Wanted array structure
const carsFinalArray = [
  {
    brand: "Opel", model: "Astra", carTypes: ["Sedan", "Hatchback", "Stationwagon"],
  },
  { brand: "Opel", model: "Corsa", carTypes: ["Hatchback"] },
  { brand: "Opel", model: "Zafira", carTypes: ["SUV"] },
];
```

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its a two step way, forEach rearranges the object into required format using key as assistant and Object.values converts it into required array.

```
 const arr = {};

 carsInitialArray.forEach(e=>{
 if(arr[e.brand+e.model])
    arr[e.brand+e.model].carTypes.push(e.carType);
 else
    arr[e.brand+e.model] ={brand:e.brand,model:e.model,carTypes:[e.carType]}
 });

 const required = Object.values(arr);
```

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/u2xm3tcn/1/